# How to prevent a cronjob from executing if another instance is already running?

Tags: cron

I want to record a stream whenever it is live automatically, so I thought of setting a cronjob that runs youtube-dl every 15 minutes to that url.

But once it is recording, how do I prevent the system from starting another recording 15 minutes later simultaneously?

Comment: You have to script it by prepending your command with some checks. You can use, for example, `pidof`.

Comment: This question is not specific to Ubuntu. One option is to use flock - https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running/82863#82863

Comment: @NGRhodes Flock works exactly right, sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for the help!

Comment: @NGRhodes Would you be willing to post an answer about that? (You're under no obligation to do so, of course, but [questions like this are on-topic for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14523/are-not-only-ubuntu-specific-questions-on-topic), and this should be answered, not closed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [flock](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/flock.1.html) for this.
flock is a little command line tool to manage locks. It works by wrapping a lock around the execution of a command and stores the state of the lock in a lock file.

You probably want to create a cron job based on a command like the following:

```
flock -n /tmp/ytdlcron.lock <your youtube dl command>
```

flock by default creates an exclusive lock (meaning only one command referencing a specific lockfile will run) and the `-n` flag causes subsequent jobs to fail until finished (rather the default which is to wait, would could leave you with lots of jobs backed up waiting to run)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion it may be useful in more general cases:

```bash
LOCK_FILE="/tmp/cron_job.lock"

# Check if lock file exists
if [ -f "$LOCK_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Lock file exists. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Create lock file
touch "$LOCK_FILE"

# Your cron job code goes here

# Remove lock file
rm "$LOCK_FILE"
```